# Docker container nodejs connection to external mysql fail

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, connection, docker

My nodejs application is connecting to mysql externally, it is all good if i start interactively by
`docker run -p 49160:8080 -t -i <image>`, and run `nodejs /src/server.js` manually.
However, when i start with daemon `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d <image>`, it will fail to connect to the external mysql.

Tried `docker start <container>` and then `docker exec <container> nodejs /src/server.js`, same error.

Tried
`docker start <container>`,`docker attach <container>` ,run `nodejs /src/server.js`, then it works.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

COPY . /src

RUN apt-get install nodejs
RUN apt-get install npm
RUN cd /src; npm install
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nodejs","/src/server.js"]
```

/src/server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql'),
myconnection = require('express-myconnection');

...

app.use(myconnection(mysql, {
  ...
},'request'));

...

app.get('/',function(req,res) {
   req.getConnection(function(err,connection) {
      if(err) 
          // giving out err here, fail to connect
```

UPDATE:

i found out that the cause was actually `nodejs /src/server.js` and `cd /src; nodejs server.js` where the former will give me the connection error and the latter works ok

so `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d <image> /bin/sh -c "cd /src; nodejs server.js"` actually works

Mark ,do you have any idea ?? still need output of `ifconfig`? thx

Comment: Interesting error... Could you try to create a script which first run `ifconfig` and then run your script and launching it as start command? In this case, which is the output?

Comment: @mark91, see my update inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that the problem is the directory from which you launch your command. Let's give a try to adding this in your Dockerfile before the CMD command:

```
 WORKDIR /src
```

PS no thanks, `ifconfig` is no more needed.

Comment: Thx @mark91 , I will try that later, but just curious why is that affecting the connection to MySQL, is it really a nodejs problem instead of docker's

Comment: I think the reason is that in your js application you are requiring or including your credentials from another file, which cannot be find in you are not executing your command in the proper directory. To be sure of this you can print them for debugging.

Comment: Yes, i am using dotenv and calling dotenv.load（） to load a .env file in the same folder of server.js.  so it is really possible that dotenv working folder is related to that of nodejs , i will verify if the .env is loaded

Comment: so it was really because of the .env file, didnt know that .env was scanned only in the current working directory.